# Implementing zip in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have `haskell` background, now trying to learn `OCaml`.

I'm trying to implement `zip` as an exercise, but I'm getting a syntax error; what's the correct syntax?

```ml
let rec zip (l1 : 'a list) (l2 : 'b list) : ('a * 'b) list = 
    match l1 l2 with
      [] _  -> []
    | _ []  -> []
    | (x::xs) (y::ys) -> (x,y)::(zip xs ys)
```

Comment: `a b` is function application. A tuple is `a, b`. I believe this is exactly the same in Haskell.

Comment: So why does the following code give a syntax error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deconstruct/construct a pair, you need to put a `,` between its members.
Which means your zip function becomes:

```ml
let rec zip (l1 : 'a list) (l2 : 'b list) : ('a * 'b) list = 
    match l1,l2 with
    | [],_  -> []
    | _,[]  -> []
    | (x::xs),(y::ys) -> (x,y)::(zip xs ys)
```

Also, note that OCaml provide or-patterns when several cases of the pattern matching return the same value

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pattern:

```
_ []
```

There is no pattern that consists of a function application. This makes it a syntax error and not just a semantic problem as in the previous expression `l1 l2`.

(Edited to give an actually erroneous pattern.)

Comment: Note: `[] _` is a valid pattern (contrarily to `_ []` for instance) because `[ ]` is a variant constructor and thus `[] _` is the `[]`-equivalent to `None _`.

Comment: I'll have to think about that, thanks. I'll fix up my answer.

Comment: I've been coding in OCaml for a few decades and didn't know you could have a pattern `None _`. Wildcards are wilder than I thought I guess.

Comment: It is the kind of feature more intended to make the life of code generators easier, rather than for human users. And there is warning, 28 [wildcard-arg-to-constant-constr], for it